# How to point multiple domains to the same website that is not the main website in Odoo 14

Tags: odoo-14

I use a multi website setup in Odoo 14 and I want to have multiple domains pointing at one domain that isn't the main domain.

example

I have 2 websites

website A is the main website, everything that isn't part of a known domain should end up here

website B is a secondary website. I want multiple domains to point to this domain. currently in Odoo there is only one field where I can put a domain..

is there any syntax with which I can put multiple domains into the domain field or Is it possible to seperate them f.e. using semicolons or commas?

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1FQx.png) - this is where I need to put multiple domains

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.